# Combining two values from different columns into one column in Datagridwiev

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, datagridview, foreach

I am using MS SQL Server and Visual Basic.

I want to combine a calculated column and  another column to add units to the calculation. (for example "200 m2")

```
DgwNewLayout.Columns(5).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0.00 " & "'" & DgwNewLayout.CurrentRow.Cells(9).Value & "'"
```

This code does that but only for first entered unit? How can I do this for each column?

Comment: Are you actually looping through all of your data grid to combine the values you want to combine?  Better still though would be to do this back in the database itself.  Create a view or stored procedure to produce data output in the style you want and then just bind your grid view to that.

Comment: I understand your concern but I am not working with a massive amounts of data. For efficiency I am going to try a stored procedure. Can you give me an example for this. (Column1, Column2 to Column3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `CellFormatting` event.

```
Private WithEvents DgwNewLayout As DataGridView

Private Sub DgwNewLayout_CellFormatting(sender As Object,
    e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs
) Handles DgwNewLayout.CellFormatting

    If e.ColumnIndex = 5 Then
        e.Value = CDbl(e.Value).ToString("0.00") &
            " " & CStr(DgwNewLayout.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(9).Value)
        e.FormattingApplied = True
    End If
End Sub
```

As Dom Sinclair says, this could have poor performance.

Comment: `Private Sub Unite_Transfer()
        For Each row In DgwNewLayout.Rows
            Dim n As Integer
            n = n + 1
            DgwNewLayout.Item(5, n - 1).Style.Format = "0.00 " & "'" & DgwNewLayout.Item(9, n - 1).Value & "'"`
        Next
    End Sub`                                                                                                          I have used this one. I could not aply your code to column(5). But thank you for your answer. Can you explain how to use your code correctly?

Comment: I've extended my code example above. Now column 5 only is formatted.
Use `Handles` with `WithEvents`, see also [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k46st1y.aspx).